# Laravel Bootstrapper Tables Chaining Methods

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to work with Laravel and the bootstrapper bundle - frankly I'm not sure whether this is a laravel question or a bootstrapper question.  However, I'm trying to figure out how to generate a table with relational data.

What I want to do is create a table with an added column that displays the roles a user has.  My tables are based on Authority's model so they are all standard with a user, role, and role_user table.

Obviously the method in the chain that is tripping me up is the 'roles' method, I can't figure out how to get the roles for a given user.  The rest of the table works as expected.

```
 echo Table::striped_open(); 
 echo Table::headers('ID','Name', 'Email', 'Roles'); 
 echo Table::body($users) 
    ->ignore('password', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    ->order('id','name','email')
    ->roles(function($users) {
        return $users['id']->roles();
        });
 echo Table::open();
```

Comment: I'm thinking I need to combine the roles with the user data in the controller and then pass that to the view with the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `$users['id']->roles()` because that doesn't make sense : you fetch an integer and then try to call something on it. What happens if you do `$users->roles()` ?

Comment: I get the following error: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given which references the bootstrappers table.php file

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is academic at this point, given the question is months old, but I figured I'd answer it to help the community at large.

You do it like this:

```
echo Table::striped_open(); 
echo Table::headers('ID','Name', 'Email', 'Roles'); 
echo Table::body($users) 
   ->ignore('password', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
   ->order('id','name','email')
   ->roles(function($user) {
       return User::find($user['id'])->roles();
       });
echo Table::open();
```

You had two issues.

The first is that you were trying to pass the $users object into the closure. You don't want to do that, partially because you could run into variable collision issues, and partially because that closure is executed on each row that's rendered, so using the singular doesn't lead to any confusion.

The second is that you were assuming that the `$user` argument passed to the closure is an instance of your model. It's not. It's an array of the model's properties. So if `roles()` is a relationship of your model, then you have to actually retrieve the model that's being converted to an array and passed into the closure.

Hope this helps!